# Is there a way to memoize a function passed from params - (useCallback) exhaustive-deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameter-passing, react-hooks, memoization

So I have this little snippet:

```
const useTest = (callbackFunc) => {
    const user = useSelector(selector.getUser); //  a value from store

    useEffect(() => {
      if (user.id === 1) {
         callbackFunc()
      }
    }, [callbackFunc, user.id])

}
```

On the code above if `callbackFunc` is not memoized (wrapped in useCallback) before passing, the `useEffect` will trigger an infinite loop.

Wrapping the function on a useCallback inside the hook will still trigger an infinite loop, so that's a no:

```
const cb = () => useCallback(() => callbackFunc, [callbackFunc]);
```

The above will trigger infite loop because `callbackFunc`.

**YES** I am well aware that I can just wrap the function inside `useCallback` before passing to this hook, my only problem with that is: there will be a high probability that other/future devs will just pass a non-memoized function when calling this hook and this is what worries me. `

I can't remove the `callbackFunc` on the `useEffect`/`useCallback` second parameter array because of `exhaustive-deps` rule - and removing it (or on this line) is also prohibited by the higher devs.

Any idea how can I possibly achieve my goal? If none thatn I'll just pray that other devs will read the hook first before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, but you won't be able to modify the callback anymore

```
const funcRef = React.useRef(null)
useEffect(() => {
 funcRef = callbackFunc
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
   if (funcRef.current){
    if (user.id === 1) {
      funcRef.current()
    }
   }
}, [funcRef, user.id])
```